# Integrating Timezones into my jquery countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timezone, countdown

I've searched all over the web, and all I'm getting is results to make new countdowns and not integrate in timezones into my jquery countdown which isn't what I'm looking for, since I'm looking to integrate the new js into my current countdown design.
Below is my js and html code I currently have which counts down from the users computer time, not from a specific timezone time.

Can someone tell me what code to input to make it based on a specified time zone (eg +8:00)

Thanks in advance:

**HTML**:

```html
<div id="counter" class="counter" data-date="July 13, 2015">
<div class="timer-col"> <span id="days"></span> <span class="timer-type">d</span> </div>
<div class="timer-col"> <span id="hours"></span> <span class="timer-type">h</span> </div>
<div class="timer-col"> <span id="minutes"></span> <span class="timer-type">m</span> </div>
<div class="timer-col"> <span id="seconds"></span> <span class="timer-type">s</span> </div>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
(function($) {

$.fn.countdown = function(toDate, callback) {
var handlers = ['seconds', 'minutes', 'hours', 'days', 'weeks', 'daysLeft'];

function delegate(scope, method) {
return function() { return method.call(scope) }
}

return this.each(function() {
// Convert
if(!(toDate instanceof Date)) {
if(String(toDate).match(/^[0-9]*$/)) {
toDate = new Date(toDate);
} else if( toDate.match(/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{2,4})\s([0-9]{1,2})\:([0-9]{2})\:([0-9]    {2})/) ||
toDate.match(/([0-9]{2,4})\/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{1,2})\s([0-9]{1,2})\:([0-9]{2})\:([0-9]{2})/)
) {
toDate = new Date(toDate);
} else if(toDate.match(/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{2,4})/) ||
toDate.match(/([0-9]{2,4})\/([0-9]{1,2})\/([0-9]{1,2})/)
) {
toDate = new Date(toDate)
} else {
throw new Error("Doesn't seen to be a valid date object or string")
}
}

var $this = $(this),
values = {},
lasting = {},
interval = $this.data('countdownInterval'),
currentDate = new Date(),
secondsLeft = Math.floor((toDate.valueOf() - currentDate.valueOf()) / 1000);

function triggerEvents() {
secondsLeft--;
if(secondsLeft < 0) {
secondsLeft = 0;
}
lasting = {
seconds : secondsLeft % 60,
minutes : Math.floor(secondsLeft / 60) % 60,
hours : Math.floor(secondsLeft / 60 / 60) % 24,
days : Math.floor(secondsLeft / 60 / 60 / 24),
weeks : Math.floor(secondsLeft / 60 / 60 / 24 / 7),
daysLeft: Math.floor(secondsLeft / 60 / 60 / 24) % 7
}
for(var i=0; i<handlers.length; i++) {
var eventName = handlers[i];
if(values[eventName] != lasting[eventName]) {
values[eventName] = lasting[eventName];
dispatchEvent(eventName);
}
}
if(secondsLeft == 0) {
stop();
dispatchEvent('finished');
}
}
triggerEvents();

function dispatchEvent(eventName) {
var event = $.Event(eventName);
event.date = new Date(new Date().valueOf() + secondsLeft);
event.value = values[eventName] || "0";
event.toDate = toDate;
event.lasting = lasting;
switch(eventName) {
case "seconds":
case "minutes":
case "hours":
event.value = event.value < 10 ? '0'+event.value.toString() : event.value.toString();
break;
default:
if(event.value) {
event.value = event.value.toString();
}
break;
}
callback.call($this, event);
}

$this.bind('remove', function() {
stop(); // If the selector is removed clear the interval for memory sake!
dispatchEvent('removed');
});

function stop() {
clearInterval(interval);
}

function start() {
$this.data('countdownInterval', setInterval(delegate($this, triggerEvents), 1000));
interval = $this.data('countdownInterval');
}

if(interval) stop();
start();
});
}
// Wrap the remove method to trigger an event when called
var removeEvent = new $.Event('remove'),
removeFunction = $.fn.remove;
$.fn.remove = function() {
$(this).trigger(removeEvent);
return removeFunction.apply(this, arguments);
}
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You might look into moment.js (http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/timezone-offset/).  I have not used it myself but it looks promising.

Comment: I've checked it out but I have basically NO JS knowledge, integrating it into my design is also extremely hard.

Comment: Ah, OK.  Well, no time like the present to learn!  I don't have much time right now to look at this, but if you could state your problem just a little more clearly that might help.  For instance, the countdown interval will be the same no matter where in the world you are, but I suspect you just want the absolute date string to be localized to the user's time zone.  Does that sound correct?

Comment: Please read [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), especially the section titled "Time Zone ! Offset".

Comment: Also, since you said you have no JavaScript knowledge, then I'm sorry but you will probably find this task too complicated.  It's unreasonable to expect someone to simply modify your code to make it work correctly without you understanding what's going on.  You may wish to instead use a pre-made solution, such as the [Free Countdown Timer for Your Website feature of timeanddate.com](http://www.timeanddate.com/clocks/freecountdown.html).